# Single interface for any hooked function

Tags: c++, windows, hook, dll-injection

I'm writing a simple Dll injection and hooking program, and everything was fine when I manually declared functions to hook like this for CreateFileA:

```
HANDLE WINAPI Hook_CreateFileA(
    LPCSTR lpFileName, DWORD dwDesiredAccess, DWORD dwShareMode, LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpSecurityAttributes,
    DWORD dwCreationDisposition, DWORD dwFlagsAndAttributes, HANDLE hTemplateFile
)
{
    ...

    return CreateFileA(lpFileName, dwDesiredAccess, dwShareMode, lpSecurityAttributes,
        dwCreationDisposition, dwFlagsAndAttributes, hTemplateFile);
}
```

But now I need to write a function that handles any function from kernel32.dll, for example. It means that I don't know anything about function except its name and hence an address.

I know a little bit about calling convention - function parameters are pushed in straight order (__stdcall) and then the function is called. I tried to write a *__declspec(naked)* function that looks like this:

```
PVOID __declspec(naked) HookAnyFunction()
    {
        /* do something */

        __asm {
            mov ebx, [esp]
            add esp, 4
            call pfnFuncAddr
            sub esp, 4
            mov[esp], ebx
            ret
        }
    }
```

pfnFuncAddr - is an address of the original function. But it crashes an application with injected Dll. I guess my code corrupts stack or something. What am I doing wrong? Hope my explanation makes sense.

Comment: Well, you're trashing the caller's `ebx` register, that could cause a crash.  Not sure there's any good way around it, mind you.

Comment: if you want have control *after* `pfnFuncAddr` you need replace original return address (in [esp]) to allocated executable memory stub, which begin from *call* instruction to your post call handler. and then must be some data - saved original return address, function name, saved parameters. as result in post handler you got address of this block (it will be return address from *call* instruction in stub) - can post log, including return value, change it if want. finally free stub block and return to original return address.

Comment: the stub chunks (all it have the same size) the best allocate at begin in big executable memory block and implement allocation/free by *InterlockedPopEntrySList* / *InterlockedPushEntrySList*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ebx` is not volatile, you cannot just write to it, you have to save/restore the original value.

Writing a generic hook function is going to be hard because the 32-bit Windows ABI has 3 calling conventions; stdcall (callee cleans the stack), cdecl (caller cleans the stack) and fastcall (first two parameters in registers but it is not used much in the public API).

If you just want to log the function calls you could probably do something like this:

```
push esp
push pfnFuncAddr
call mylogger ; assumed to be stdcall in this case, it can also change the jump
jmp eax
```

and `FARPROC __stdcall mylogger(FARPROC function, SIZE_T stackaddress) { ...; return function; }` (remember that `esp` has changed so you have to adjust the stack parameter by 8+4 bytes if you want to log the contents of the stack.) If you care about fastcall you also have to push the registers but there is no way for a generic logger to know if the first parameters are on the stack or in registers.

Comment: Thanks! That's definitely what I need!